# is there Any Way to edit Many To Many Relation Ship without attaching-detaching in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After spending hours and following the code, I found that Laravel has no way of Editing The Intermediate table in Many To Many Relation without detaching and attaching ..
This is okay but it has a big disadvantage.
Applying the app on big scale, the `id` index increases rapidly.
So I wonder if there are anyway ? And how to overcome this ID problems 
(I though about cron jobs to reindex it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is! Suppose you have this database structure, where `User` and `Group` share a many-to-many relationship, with a `valid` field in the pivot (intermediary) table.

```
+-------------+  +-------------+  +-------------+
| users       |  | groups      |  | group_user  |
+-------------+  +-------------+  +-------------+
| id          |  | id          |  | group_id    |
| name        |  | name        |  | user_id     |
| email       |  | desc        |  | valid       |
+-------------+  +-------------+  +-------------+
```

Now, since the `valid` column is not strictly necessary for the relationship, you'll have to tell Laravel to specifically fetch this row. For the sake of simplicity, I'll call it right in the example, **but if you need it very often, you'd probably want to put that in the model relationship itself**, on `User`.`groups` and `Group`.`users` methods.

```
// Retrive the user with ID one
$user = User::find(1);

// This tells Laravel to fetch the `valid` column, when
// the user's groups
$userGroups = $user->groups()->withPivot('valid')->get();

// Get the first group
$firstGroup  = $userGroups->first();

// Change the `valid` value for that first group
$firstGroup->pivot->valid = true;

// Save the changes
$firstGroup->pivot->save();
```

Comment: I really Tried this before, but it doesn't work with group_id and user_id .. Simply the query log uses them as the where clause.
So  If I updated user_id or group_id, The where clause will not be accurate and it may lead to non-intended update